# Как вставить ссылку на сайт в textview в eclipse

Tags: android

Как вставить ссылку на сайт в textview в eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:text="http://hashcode.ru/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй в коде добавить еще это:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```